# Apache CXF/JAXB Generate default constructor for required elements/attributes

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, wsdl, cxf

I have just started working with Apache CXF (v2.7.6). I am generating a client for a WSDL using the wsdl2java like:

```
wsdl2java -client -d src -exsh true -dns true -dex true -xjc-Xdv -wsdlLocation file:/some.wsdl -verbose -defaultValues -fe jaxws -db jaxb -wv 1.1 some.wsdl
```

In the wsdl I have some elements with required attributes like:

```
<element name="Attribute">
    <complexType>
        <attribute name="id" type="string" use="required"></attribute>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

For these elements I'd like to get default constructors generated in the java code. Currently it generates:

```
public static class Attribute {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "anySimpleType")
    protected String id;
```

And I'd like something like:

```
public static class Attribute {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "anySimpleType")
    protected String id = new String("");
```

I've searched quite a while (CXF, JAXB options) but found nothing yet.

Is it possible to generate java code like I want? If so, could you point me in the right direction (custom binding file?) or provide me a small sample on how to do it?

Many thanks in advance,

JG

Comment: Can you explain why you want this? I ask because in the specific case you provide, the attribute is required, so the value would always be populated... and your default constructor effectively never used (or rather, called and almost immediately overwritten). So if you can tell us why you want this, perhaps somebody can come up with an answer that does what you need rather than what you want. :)

Comment: Hi dcsohl, many thanks for your comments. In the case of a String element/attribute, you're completely right. But I want to apply this as well for other elements. If I don't have a constructor, I cannot do something like: `code`getAnElement().getItsSubelement().setSomeValueInIt() cause I get an NPE when accessing itsSubelement. Having the default constructors would avoid this.

Comment: I'm getting a better picture here... but in the case of child elements, null truly is the best representation if the parent element has no children. If you have a default constructor, you are creating a child element, and it's not a true representation of the XML structure in the circumstances you are concerned about.

Comment: @dcsohl The one thing that it's nice to have is a default empty collection instance for fields that hold suitable types (lists, arrays, etc.) It's not critical though; writing the `null` check out just makes things verbose…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by creating an XJC Plugin. Not that difficult (since I am familiar with generating code with the com.sun.codemodel.* classes) after having a look at:

- https://java.net/projects/jaxb2-commons/pages/Home
- https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/06/writing_a_plugi.html

Answer (score 0):

I did not test it myself, but is seems you can implement the  [org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.DefaultValueProvider](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest-2.4.x/org/apache/cxf/tools/wsdlto/core/DefaultValueProvider.html) interface and pass it to the wsdl2java command line using the "defaultValues" parameter.

Have a look [there](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html) for the syntax of "defaultValues"

Let me know if it works.

Edit: as dcsohl said, your requirement seems strange and maybe we miss something so please explain the context a little bit more

Comment: Hi Francois, I tried your suggestion, but the generated values go into the generated implementation of the client class, not in the classes representing the xsd elements.